# Running an async method inside a relaycommand using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

I'm developing an asynchronous application using WPF and MVVM, but I can't seem to get an async method to run inside my relaycommand.

I have a button on my WPF **view** hooked up to a relaycommand in my **viewmodel**, which trys to call an async method in my **model** to return a list of results:

```
/// <summary>
/// Search results 
/// </summary>
private ObservableCollection<string> _searchResults = new ObservableCollection<string>(); 
public IList<string> SearchResults
{
    get { return _searchResults; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Search button command
/// </summary>
private ICommand _searchCommand;
public ICommand SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
        _searchCommand = new RelayCommand(
            async() =>
            {
                SearchResults.Clear();
                var results = await DockFindModel.SearchAsync(_selectedSearchableLayer, _searchString);
                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    SearchResults.Add(item);
                }                    
                //notify results have changed
                NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SearchResults);
            },
            () => bAppRunning); //command will only execute if app is running
        return _searchCommand;
    }
}
```

However I get the following exception when the relaycommand tries to execute:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> > Additional information: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either
> >     by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a
> >     result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread.

I've tried a number of things in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170923/relay-command-can-execute-and-a-task) to try and resolve the issue with no luck. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: What is the inner exception?

Comment: What does your RelayCommand looks like?

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks anyway folks.

Comment: Fixed it or dodged it?

Comment: I know I'm waking up an old thread here but shouldn't you be awaiting the lambda function? I would have tried changing `async() =>` to `async() => await`.

Comment: For anyone coming here and not satisfied with accepted answer, go to [https://reactiveui.net/](https://reactiveui.net/) and take a look at ReactiveCommand -  it makes working with async commands a blast

Comment: This is from forever ago, so I won't dig too deep, but the first problem I see is that the getter returns a new `RelayCommand` every time it's accessed. That's never what you want. Instead, checking `_searchCommand` for null and only assigning it then (lazy initialization), or just initialize it in your constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I actually managed to resolve the issue by making a change to the way I run my async method.

I changed this:

```
var results = await DockFindModel.SearchAsync();
```

To this:

```
var results = await QueuedTask.Run(() => DockFindModel.SearchAsync());
```

Although i'm a bit confused as to why I need to await Task.Run() when relaycommand is already accepting async lambda. I'm sure it'll become clear with time however.

Thanks to those who commented.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure where your RelayCommand is coming from (MVVM framework or custom implementation) but consider using an async version.

```
public class AsyncRelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<object, Task> execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> canExecute;

    private long isExecuting;

    public AsyncRelayCommand(Func<object, Task> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute ?? (o => true);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (Interlocked.Read(ref isExecuting) != 0)
            return false;

        return canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref isExecuting, 1);
        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        try
        {
            await execute(parameter);
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref isExecuting, 0);
            RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there is an exception in `execute`, the visual studio debugger will highlight the `await execute(parameter);` line. I was expecting the debugger to highlight the actual erroneous line inside the `execute` delegate. Can we somehow manage this?

Answer (score 0):

That `RelayCommand` class is probably accepting a parameter of type `Action`. Since you are passing an async lambda, we are having an `async void` scenario here.
Your code will be **fired and forgot**. Consider using an ICommand implementation that takes `Func<Task>` as a parameter instead of `Action`.